# Deployment failed Error : - (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I have updated my eclipse and gwt using [Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/) and [GWT Eclipse Plugin](http://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/) .
Now i have imported my existing project GWT 2.6.1 in new updated environment then i have converted it into google app engine project using Configure > Convert to App Engine Project. and also enable GWT SDM builder using Configure > Enable GWT SDM builder. now i am deploying the project then i am getting ERROR :gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred. as shown below : -

```
Configurations to update:

descriptor:      [C:\NEON Projects\23 nov 2017\.metadata\.plugins\com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.deploy\tmp\1511437524653\staging\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\cron.yaml]
type:            [cron jobs]
target project:  [evadev0013]


descriptor:      [C:\NEON Projects\23 nov 2017\.metadata\.plugins\com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.deploy\tmp\1511437524653\staging\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\index.yaml]
type:            [datastore indexes]
target project:  [evadev0013]


descriptor:      [C:\NEON Projects\23 nov 2017\.metadata\.plugins\com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.deploy\tmp\1511437524653\staging\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\queue.yaml]
type:            [task queues]
target project:  [evadev0013]


Beginning deployment of service [default]...
Some files were skipped. Pass `--verbosity=info` to see which ones.
You may also view the gcloud log file, found at
[C:\Users\Nitin\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs\2017.11.23\17.18.18.741000.log].
#============================================================#
#= Uploading 309 files to Google Cloud Storage              =#
#============================================================#
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...
.............................failed.
{"version": "0.0.1", "verbosity": "ERROR", "timestamp": "2017-11-23T12:02:07.154Z", "message": "(gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred."}
```

Why i am getting this error ? i am not able deploy.

any help ?

Comment: Could you please ensure you check that you have the latest `gcloud` updates by running `gcloud components update`?

Answer (score 0):

Some users have reported that this error may occur because of hidden files being included, such as `Icon^M` (or perhaps `.DS_Store` files?) on MacOS. Clearing these files may bring you success.

https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/google-appengine/a096680b-7f83-4802-a684-b712fe5d004d%40googlegroups.com